# How to change the "recent apps tray" icon on android?

Tags: android

After changing my app's icon, the icon in the "recent apps tray" remains Android's default. I want to change it but cannot find any way to do so. Every single app I've ever used got it's own icon there (although noticed some of them left there their old icon) so I don't want to be any different.

The "recent apps tray" looks like the following example:

[recent apps tray example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufink.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its probably the icon in your manifest.  Most likely whatever app you're showing there just doesn't refresh itself until you reboot.  But I have no idea, since that's not standard android UI-  my guess is its a custom launcher or an OEM custom launcher.

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same issue. After a lot of re-installations (with micro-changes), I finally decided to just reboot my phone. And that did it.

Comment: reboot it is!!!

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings and clear the app data or just reinstall it, if it does not work then you are not setting your icon correctly on your manifest

Comment: I cleared it's data, deleted it and installed again. Didn't work...
The menifest contains the followings:
android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

Comment: Then the problem should be the device itself perhaps the launcher or something, try it on another device

Answer (score 0):

You should add this line:

```
android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

In your manifest file in `<application>` tag like:

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher" <---- this line
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```